# image not refreshing when form submitted with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project where users can upload their profile image, so I created an Ajax form. The form is being submitted successfully but it does not refreshes the new image that is uploaded by the user

This is my form code

```
  <label data-toggle="tooltip" title="Your Avatar">
      <img src="../assets/img/avatar/<?= $user->avatar() ?>" class="profile-settings-avatar" id="avatar" alt="Profile Avatar" />
    <input id="avatar-file-input" type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control" style="display:none;"/>
 </label>
```

This is my ajax code, Im using Ajax Form to submit it with ajax, it tried to change the src with new src when ajax completed but doesn't works

```
// Profile Settings Ajax
$(document).ready(function() { 
  let avatar = $('#avatar').attr('src');
  $('#form').ajaxForm(function(){
      avatar = $('#avatar').attr('src');
      $.notify("Your card has been updated successfully!", "success");
  }); 
});
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: `$('#avatar').attr('src');` update `$('#avatar').attr('src',avatar);`

Comment: also you can try https://www.dorcode.com/questions/46/picture-onupload-button

Answer (score 0):

you said that you submit it with ajax, but i dont see a url in ajaxForm paramter, how can you upload an image?

this is example ajaxform function

```
$("#theForm").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})
```

and if you want upload an image then an image directly shows in img element, you can use onchange event in input type file for uploading image than get return value from upload image ajax to change attribute src

Comment: ajaxForm is a plugin for jquery ajax, no parameters needed